# Web Project is not deploying

Tags: html, spring, maven, wildfly, web-deployment

When I try to deploy a web project, Wildfly always returns me this error:

```
12:08:58,929 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."focusoc-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."focusoc-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:283)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
... 10 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:40)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:849)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:342)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:420)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:217)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:341)
... 21 more
```

I don't know what it is missing in the project, and I don't know what to do. In localhost I also have a keycloak server, but it doesn't have bother this one, don't it?

Comment: You JSF configuration is wrong somehow

Comment: In the web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The main problem that I had it is what I configured it as Maven Project, and I didn't compile it as Maven.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else has this, but maven wasn't the problem, in my case this error was given because I had no beans.xml (and apparently, JSF explicitly requires one).

Answer (score 2):

create the file **beans.xml** on **WEB-INF/** and add to it this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding beans.xml would solve your problem.

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, its solved by adding an "empty" `beans.xml` on `WEB-INF/` directory.
See [here](http://fritzthecat-blog.blogspot.com/2019/08/jsf-23-maven-project-in-eclipse.html) for more detail.